# jQuery searching multiple levels of children

Tags: jquery

I have a parent div class called `common-end`.

I have many div's of this class, an example of how it looks is:

```
<div class="item question common-end">
    <label>label</label>
    <div>
       <textarea name="name1" id="text1" class="deep-item form-control input-lg" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not all `common-end` div's have this structure. There might be multiple layers of nesting.

The only thing I will know for sure, is that SOMEWHERE inside `common-end` there will be something with the class `deep-item` (in this case it's on the textarea).

What is a jQuery selector I can use to find `deep-item` SOMEWHERE inside `common-end`?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As RyanW mentioned, the simplest selector is that similar to a CSS selector:

```
var $deepItems = $('.common-end .deep-item');
```

However, I should mention that the way jQuery works, in this scenario, is to search right to left. So, if you have `.deep-item` elements in elements other than `.common-end` elements (or just simply have very few `.common-end` elements) you should give jQuery the opportunity to scope it (making it slightly faster):

```
var $deepItems = $('.deep-item', '.common-end')
// equivalent to:
var $deepItems = $('.common-end').find('.deep-item')
```

This allows jQuery to simply find all `.common-end` elements *first*, then begin searching within for `.deep-item` (instead of finding all `.deep-item`s and confirming they're nested within a `.common-end`).

This may not be as big an issue, given you have specific classes to search for. However, if you were starting with a class and grabbing a specific tag, it could become a problem. Picture the following:

```
$('.common-end div');
```

Which would grab every `<div>` on the page, then check if it's a descendent of `.common-end`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.common-end .deep-item')
```

This will return all deep-item's within a common-end.  If there is a specific on you are looking for, you can do something like below:

```
var el = $(<selector to the common-end i care about);
var deepItem = el.find('.deep-item');
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you use selectors in the same way you use them in css.

```
$('.common-end > .deep-item') //this will select only direct children
$('.common-end .deep-item') //this will select all children, even if nested under multiple levels
```

According to your question, you need the second one.